# Firebase v9: Firebase is not updating the user password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase version `9` and react. I'm trying to update the password of the user. The code for doing that is as follows:

```
 await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credentials)
        .then(async () => {
          console.log(password, auth.currentUser);
          await updatePassword(auth.currentUser as any, password.trim())
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Password upd");
              // await signOut(auth).finally(() => navigate("/"));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              this.setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                error: {
                  field: "confirmPassword",
                  value: error.message,
                },
              }));
              return;
            });
        })
```

I'm not getting any error and the i can be able to see in the console logs the message `"Password upd"` but the password is not updating for some reason. What maybe possibly the problem here?

Comment: The use of the two Firebase Auth methods seems correct. What happens if you avoid mixing `async/await` and `then()`, as follows: `try {
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credentials);
    await updatePassword(auth.currentUser as any, password.trim())
    console.log("password updated")
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}`. To be included in a async function. Note that with your current code you don't catch errors from the call to `reauthenticateWithCredential()`...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for your response, wvwn if i do that i'ts still not working.

Comment: No error logged in the catch block?

Comment: Also can you give a try without reathenticating, just to see the result?